# How to return statement in javascript if the answer second input always wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to get some value for prime number and in my code include prompt for user to input the number but first number is must less than second number if second number is less than first number it show statement to user for input greater number than first until second input greater than first.

this is my code

```js
var firstInput = prompt("First Number :");
var secondInput = prompt("Second Number : ");

if(secondInput < firstInput){
 secondInput = prompt("Please input Number greater than First Number: ");
};

function isPrime(num) {
    for ( var i = 2; i < num; i++ ) {
        if ( num % i === 0 ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function display(firstInput, secondInput) {
    var prime = [];
    for ( var i = firstInput; i < secondInput; i++ ) {
        if ( isPrime(i) ) {
            prime.push(i);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = prime;
}

display(firstInput, secondInput);
```

```html
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Change the `if` to a `while`.

Comment: I want second number greater than first number. if second number always less than first number show prompt or warning to input greater number than first.

Comment: Try parseFloat(secondInput) < parseFloat(firstInput)

Comment: Oke thanks @nnnnnn

Comment: I didn't understand `always`. How you count always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `if` statement to a `while` loop if you want to repeat your `prompt`:

```js
var firstInput = +prompt("First Number :");
var secondInput = +prompt("Second Number : ");

while (secondInput < firstInput) {
  secondInput = +prompt("Please input Number greater than First Number: ");
}

function isPrime(num) {
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function display(firstInput, secondInput) {
  var prime = [];
  for (var i = firstInput; i < secondInput; i++) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
      prime.push(i);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = prime;
}

display(firstInput, secondInput);
```

```html
<span id="demo"></span>
```